# What is invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programing in python, as I'm am trying to learn to program because it will be useful when I am trying to get my dream job. So I am trying to make a calculator, but I get this message "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'"

in this I have made a overly complicated calculator, I want to make it so that it will repeat the steps. in this case I want it to have the ability to change the first number to the answer of the previous answer, so that you can multiply a answer, then multiply the answer of that, but I get invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Comment: I don't know how this website works so tell me if there are pictures cause I do not see them

Comment: Could you post the method that includes the line that's failing?

Comment: put the code itself for your program, it is not obvious what's happening

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience that was caused by this, I did not do enough research. But I have to learn somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a module as an integer, that is not exactly right.

Your algorithm should look like this

```
currentValue = None
while True:
    number = int(input('give me a number'))
    next = input('yes to restart, Yes to continue)
    if next == 'yes':
       anotherNumber = int(input('give me another number'))
       currentValue = number * anotherNumber
    elif next == 'Yes':
       currentValue = number * currentValue
    else:
       print('Bye')
       break

    print('Total', currentValue)
```